# Open iphone camera from web for scanning qr codes

Tags: jquery, iphone

I would like to add a button on a website to launch the iphone camera in order to scan QR Codes. After adding a simple  tag the camera launches it won't scan anything. Here are the codes I tried:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" id="capture" capture="camera"> and
<input type="file" accept="video/*" id="capture" capture="camcorder"> and <input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera">
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Why you think iPhone camera able to scan QR code?

Comment: Since OS11 you can use the camera to scan qr codes